# vlookup style query in sql?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a really simple vlookup query I want to write in sql but cant seem to apply any of the examples from previous questions to my data.

I have two tables, totalstats which has the agentnumber column, and Agentref which lists every agentname against the agentnumber.

I want to do a really simple query to join the two tables and create a new column in totalstats which shows the agent name against each agentnumber.

I feel like this should be simple to do but i'm getting really stuck! Would appreciate any help, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
   Agentref.AGENTNUMBER
   ,totalstats.stat
FROM
   totalstats 
JOIN
   Agentref
ON 
   totalstats.AGENTNUMBER=Agentref.AGENTNUMBER
```

**UPDATE:**

assuming the Agentname is in a column like "AGENTNAME"

```
select
   Agentref.AGENTNUMBER
   ,Agentref.AGENTNAME
   ,convert(varchar(255),Agentref.AGENTNUMBER)+' '+Agentref.AGENTNAME as NumberName
   ,totalstats.stat
FROM
   totalstats 
JOIN
   Agentref
ON 
   totalstats.AGENTNUMBER=Agentref.AGENTNUMBER
```

convert(varchar(255),Agentref.AGENTNUMBER)+' '+Agentref.AGENTNAME
puts Number and Name in the same column with a blank inbetween

Comment: 24 seconds in it - god damn! :-)

Comment: Was not expecting an answer that fast! Thank you :)

Comment: But i still don't have an additional column with the agent name :S

Comment: Sorry my badm it's added to new columns to the end of the tabl;es called agentID and agent name ,but both columns are populated with null

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
SELECT
*
FROM
dbo.TotalStats TS
LEFT JOIN
dbo.AgentRef AR ON TS.AgentNumber = AR.AgentNumber
```

That is, assuming you've structured the data as I think you have.

Comment: @Der u, I know, I know! but I don't know if there are any other columns that might want to be taken.  I'd expect the asker to know only to return the data required in the actual query! :-)